# Удаление нечётных элементов в бинарном дереве С++

Tags: c++, бинарное-дерево

Задача более чем простая, но ввела меня в ступор... Необходимо из обыкновенного бинарного дерева удалить все нечётные элементы и вывести это же новое дерево на экран. Пользователь вводит int n - количество элементов и сами элементы дерева. Вот что я смог написать (где-то сам, где-то взял из Интернета)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "bintree.h"

void paste_node(Tree ** tr, int x) //процедура вставки нового узла
{
    Tree *tree_bin;
    if ((*tr) == NULL) {  //если дерево пусто, то
        tree_bin = (Tree *)malloc(sizeof(Tree));  //возвращаем указатель на первый байт, если памяти не хватает на нулевой,
                                                  //с помощью функции malloc
        tree_bin->item = x; //inf = x
        tree_bin->lchild = tree_bin->rchild = NULL; //ссылки на левого и правого ребёнка NULL
        *tr = tree_bin;
        return; //выход из процедуры
    }

    if (x < (*tr)->item) { //если вводимое значение меньше текущего значения, то
        paste_node(&((*tr)->lchild), x); //вызываем рекурсивно функцию paste_node от левого ребёнка и x
    }
    else { //иначе
        paste_node(&((*tr)->rchild), x); //от правого ребёнка  и х
    }
}

Tree * minimum(Tree *tr)
{
    if (!tr->lchild->lchild) return tr;
    return minimum(tr->lchild);
}

void delete_node(Tree** tr, int num, Tree* parent) //процедура удаления элемента
{
    if (!(*tr)) return; //если дерево пусто, выход из процедуры

    if (num < (*tr)->item)
        delete_node(&((*tr)->lchild), num, *tr);
    else if (num >(*tr)->item)
        delete_node(&((*tr)->rchild), num, *tr);
    else {

        if (!(*tr)->lchild && !(*tr)->rchild) {//Если детей у удаляемого узла нет, то перед нами самый простой случай - листовой узел.

            if (parent) {//Родителю данного узла надо сообщить о том, что потомка у него теперь нет 

                if (parent->lchild) {

                    if (parent->lchild->item == (*tr)->item) { //Если удаляется левый потомок

                        parent->lchild = NULL;
                    }
                }
                if (parent->rchild) {

                    if (parent->rchild->item == (*tr)->item) { //Если удаляется правый потомок

                        parent->rchild = NULL;
                    }
                }
            }
            free(*tr); // Освобождаем память
            *tr = NULL;
        }
        else if (!(*tr)->lchild || !(*tr)->rchild) { // Если у удаляемой вершины есть хотя бы один потомок

            Tree* nodeToRemove = NULL;
            if ((*tr)->lchild) { //Находим того самого единственного потомка удаляемой вершины

                nodeToRemove = (*tr)->lchild;
            }
            else {

                nodeToRemove = (*tr)->rchild;
            }
            //Скопировать все данные из единственного потомка удаляемой вершины
            (*tr)->lchild = nodeToRemove->lchild;
            (*tr)->rchild = nodeToRemove->rchild;
            (*tr)->item = nodeToRemove->item;
            //Освободить память, выделенную ранее для данного потомка
            free(nodeToRemove);
        }
        else { //Если у удаляемой вершины есть оба потомка, то согласно алгоритму необходимо найти наименьший элемент в правом поддереве удаляемого элемента

            if (!(*tr)->rchild->lchild) { //Если у правого поддерева нет левых потомков, то это означает, что у всех потомков значение ключа больше,
                                          //а значит надо просто скопировать значения из правого потомка в удаляемый элемент
                (*tr)->item = (*tr)->rchild->item; // Скопировать значение из правого потомка
                Tree* rightRIghtChild = (*tr)->rchild->rchild;
                free((*tr)->rchild); // Освбодить память, выделенную для правого потомка
                (*tr)->rchild = rightRIghtChild;
            }
            else {

                Tree* minNodeParent = minimum((*tr)->rchild); //Поиск наименьшего элемента в правом поддереве (он обязательно найдётся, случай когда его нет был разобран выше)
                (*tr)->item = minNodeParent->lchild->item; //Скопировать значение из наименьшего жлемента в правом поддереве в удаляемый элемент
                free(minNodeParent->lchild);
                minNodeParent->lchild = NULL;
            }
        }
    }
}

void print_tree(Tree *tr, int depth)
{
    if (tr != NULL) {
        print_tree(tr->lchild, depth + 1);
        for (int i = 0; i < depth; ++i) printf("   ");
        printf("%d<\n", tr->item);
        print_tree(tr->rchild, depth + 1);
    }
}

void delete_nechet(Tree *tr)
{
    if (!tr) return;
    if (tr->item % 2 != 0) delete_node(*tr, tr->item, NULL);
    if (tr->lchild != NULL) delete_nechet(*tr->lchild);
    if (tr->rchild != NULL) delete_nechet(*tr->rchild);
}

int main() {
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    Tree tr;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        int x;
        cin >> x;
        paste_node(tr, x);
    }
    delete_nechet(*tr);
    print_tree(tr, 0);
    return 0;
}
```

Самая первая ошибка, которая вылазит на этапе компиляции - это отсутствие библиотеки bintree.h, а дальшеее...

Как это можно исправить? Что я делаю не так? Буду рад любой помощи

Comment: Это вы, как бы пояснить... в ситуации грабителя, который спер сейф, но ключ оставил, а взломать без ключа - не выходит :) В этом заголовочном файле все необходимые объявления - например, что такое `Tree`...

Answer (score 0):

В `"bintree.h"` очевидно, определяется структура узла (Tree). Это можно сделать самостоятельно.

Чтобы не рубить сук, на котором сидишь, лучше сделать так - сначала удаляем нечётные в поддеревьях, потом проверяем корень

```
void delete_nechet(Tree *tr)
{
    if (!tr) return;
    if (tr->lchild <> NULL) delete_nechet(*tr->lchild);
    if (tr->rchild <> NULL) delete_nechet(*tr->rchild);

    if (tr->item % 2 != 0) delete_node(*tr, tr->item, NULL);

}
```

Comment: Что за оператор такой интересный "<>"?)

Comment: @Михаил Муругов "не равно" из Паскаля :)